# Customizing database error messages during run time

Tags: jasperserver

I have a report connected to sql server. There are parameters used to run the report, however, the filters have a lot of values in each one of them. When the user tries to select all the values in the filter and tries to run the report, I get the error 'Too many parameters were provided . The maximum is 2100.' This message is okay, but , is there a way to customize this error message, say, instead of the message mentioned , I would want to show "Please select fewer parameters and proceed"?

I am using jaspersoft 6.1. I have understood how to edit jasper server messages files, to obtain customized messages. However, this is a database error and I do not find any files on the jasper server wherein I can customize this error message

The code is simple where in the parameters are passed through $X{}

Expected result = Customize the database error message to user understandable message
Actual result = Unable to customize the error message

Comment: I have never used jasper-server but this is clearly a database error, hence error is not thrown by jasper but by the library that you are using to query database (you will not find this case in server message files) . The best bet probably is that you modify the jasper-reports server page that displays error (handle this special case and change the message) I found this that can be useful https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-display-custom-error-message-jasperreports-server

Comment: Thank you Alex. We will try this out